# iOS app to capture video from screen

Tags: ios

Is there a chance of possibility to create an iOS application which would record video from screen and save it on device?

I'm talking about recording everything that happens on screen not only within bounds of this application.
 The app works in background and captures everything.
I'm playing a game - it is recording, I'm watching video - it is recording.

I'm 99 percent sure it's impossible, but maybe there's something I'm unaware of.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090184/how-does-the-ios-app-display-recorder-record-the-screen-without-using-private-ap

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible without using the private API.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible.

You can try to install [AirServer](http://www.airserver.com/) application on your MAC, then turn on mirroring on your iOS device and stream  your screen to your MAC and use 3rd party applications to capture your screen on the MAC