# Can I use IOSurface framework to record screen in production

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

Will apple reject my app if I use IOSurface framework for making a video of my app

Comment: You should be able to answer this question yourself. Is it a public framework on iOS? If not (which is true at the time of writing this comment), you can't submit it to the App Store.

Comment: You can't submit with IOSurface linked to your app (as David mentioned above), but if you just want to make a demo video (using a development build for instance), then you won't have any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you link IOSurface Apple will reject your app.

Some project on the store are using it but they may load it at run time:

[How does the iOS app Display Recorder record the screen without using private API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090184/how-does-the-ios-app-display-recorder-record-the-screen-without-using-private-ap)