# How does kamcord support screen recording in iOS

Tags: ios, screen

How can I support screen video recording in my app.
I came across IOSurface framework but I am afraid apple will reject my app if I use it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use IOSurface framework to record screen in production](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162334/can-i-use-iosurface-framework-to-record-screen-in-production)

Comment: i dont think kamcord uses IOSurface as the apps that use it are live in app store so this is not a copy of that question

Comment: Both questions can be rephrased as "Can I record the screen in iOS without using A private framework such as IOSurface"

Comment: From looking at the Kamcord documentation you need to insert the Kamcord calls into your app to record the frames you are generating so it doesn't use private Apis.