# How can I record the screen on my iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone

How can I record the screen on my iPhone? I want to record the iPhone screen with the private API, but I can't find any header to do this. [I'm not sure this can be used after iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090184/how-does-the-ios-app-display-recorder-record-the-screen-without-using-private-ap/11105783).

Does anyone have any idea how to achieve this? Please help.

Comment: Programmatically?

Comment: Yeah,Programmatically...my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold down the Home key.  Then push the button on the top right of the device.  At the moment I can't remember it's name.

Comment: That's a screenshot, not a recording.

Comment: My mistake.  You meant programmatically.  I should have recognized it.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout this [ASScreenRecorder](https://github.com/alskipp/ASScreenRecorder).  In this tutorial, it will record screen on Tap Gesture, but you can directly used where you need it.

Comment: yeah, thanks. But this demo can just record own app. And I want to record the other app screen.

Comment: I don't think is there any feature to record one application from another app.

Comment: https://github.com/xindawndev/RecordMyScreen-iOS10 .But it don't open source. I don't konw how to do this.